# Is there Arel.sql(for an array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I've just been bit by the warning

> ... Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This
>   method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request
>   parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by
>   wrapping them in Arel.sql()...

Cool.  I'd already checked the column choices against the column names, so I'm in good shape.  But they are a list of values, not just a single string.  So I've added

```
['some', 'column', 'names'].map{ |string| Arel.sql(string) }
```

three times in the same method (for different groups of things).  So I'm wondering if there is a shorthand like:

```
Arel.sql_elements(['some', 'list', 'of', 'strings'])
```

Does it exist and I'm not finding it - or am I going to monkey patch it in?